# Add 'timestamp' of last email sent to a particular contact, through gmail, to google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp, gmail, google-workspace

My objective is to track the last conversation that I have with my clients and take appropriate steps before being too late and go out of touch.

So I am looking for a way to collect the time information about the last email sent to a particular contact from my inbox and save it in google sheets. So would love to know if there is a simple code that I can input to get it running.

I am not a coder, so any assistance would be helpful. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the Gmail API and with the SpreadsheetApp class. The procedure could be:

1. [List](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) the emails to get the IDs. You can perform advanced search queries with the `q` parameter.
2. Get the [internalDate](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages#internalDate) using the email Id.
3. Update the Sheet with the [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue).

In the links you will see plenty examples of how to use the methods.